# How to save email as draft in Outlook 2003 programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, email, outlook

I am working on an VB.NET app which constructs emails programmatically.

This app can be used by different people at the same time so I thought that having a "central" email mailbox would be appropriate. The users would then have "links" (not sure of the correct term) to that central mailbox through their local copy of Outlook.

I want to be able to save these emails so that all users can see the generated emails in the "Drafts" folder of their Outlook so that they can check the emails first for any errors and then send it off.

I was originally simply talking directly to the Outlook app on the server using Microsoft.Office.Interop but have since read that it is not recommended for use in this sort of scenario.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using MS Exchange as the mail/communication server? You might want to think about planting the mails into the exchange's repository which will be picked up by the users via outlook. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, I had thought about this. I have tried googling for a way to this and have found something called WebDav. It seems very complicated. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into VBA macros. (http://blogs.msdn.com/synergist/archive/2007/05/23/adding-a-vba-macro-to-outlook.aspx)